# undeclared Identifier error

Tags: c++, opengl

I am learning computer graphics using opengl and c++. when I am trying to run my code It shows the following error:

'myDisplay' undeclared identifier. Although thats already declared. please help me as I am new to OGL and c++.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<glut.h>
#include "RGBA.h"

using namespace std;

int screenWidth= 640;
int screenHeight= 480;

RGBApixmap pix[2];

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
glutInitWindowPosition(30,30);
glutCreateWindow("Mario and Bhoot");

pix[0].readBMPFile("bg.bmp");

pix[1].readBMPFile("marioStanding.bmp");
pix[1].setChromaKey(192,192,192);

glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
glutMainLoop();

return 0;

}

void myDisplay(void)
{
glClearColor(0.035,0.050,0.274,0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1,0,0);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluOrtho2D(0,20,0,20);

glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST);
glAlphaFunc(GL_EQUAL,1.0);

glPixelZoom(1,1);
glRasterPos2i(-20,-20);
pix[0].mDraw();

glRasterPos2i(-18,-20);
glPixelZoom(1.5,1.5);
pix[1].mDraw();

//glBegin


glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: `myDisplay` is defined _after_ you try to use it in `main`.  You'll need to add a prototype declaration before its first use.  C++ scans files sequentially when parsing... except in class bodies.  Kind of.

Comment: I changed the order and it worked without adding a prototype declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Sean Middleditch said, In C/C++ you must declare functions before tu use them:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
#include<glut.h>
#include "RGBA.h"

using namespace std;

void myDisplay(void);
int main(int, char**);
glutSwapBuffers();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
...
```

Ordering functions work also, but I think it is not a good programming practice:

```
myDisplay(void)
{
...
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
...
}
...
```

When there is a circular dependence of two function (A() call B() and B() call A) for any recursive algorithm, ordering functions is not possible.

In this case, the prototype declaration is the only solution. Mix both solution is ugly/problematic. Also, getting all declarations into a .h file has many advantages.

Comment: I changed the order and it worked without adding a prototype declaration!